# Weird behaviour of compareTo(GregorianCalendar c)

Tags: java, compareto

Could you tell me why the fillowing code:

```
int a = new GregorianCalendar(2015,3,31,7,45).compareTo(
        new GregorianCalendar(2015,4,1,7,45);
System.out.println(a);
```

prints out 0?

Is there a way to make it work right?

PS: I need to sort strings out by date and I use this comparator:

```
array.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(o1.replaceAll(p, "$7")),
                Integer.parseInt(o1.replaceAll(p, "$6")), Integer.parseInt(o1.replaceAll(p, "$5")),
                Integer.parseInt(o1.replaceAll(p, "$8")), Integer.parseInt(o1.replaceAll(p, "$9")));
        GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(o2.replaceAll(p, "$7")),
                Integer.parseInt(o2.replaceAll(p, "$6")), Integer.parseInt(o2.replaceAll(p, "$5")),
                Integer.parseInt(o2.replaceAll(p, "$8")), Integer.parseInt(o2.replaceAll(p, "$9")));
        return cal1.compareTo(cal2);
    }
});
```

It uses regular expressions, but it is sorted correctly and only the dates provided are not sorted right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing "April 31st" with May 1st. There *is* no April 31st, so it's rolling over to May 1st anyway. (Okay, it would make more sense to just throw an exception, but hey... that's far from the worst piece of API design in `Calendar`.)

I would strongly recommend using `SimpleDateFormat` to parse string representations of date/time values, instead of doing it yourself. Aside from anything else, `SimpleDateFormat` "knows" that months are 0-based in Java... which is the basic bug you've fallen foul of. The code would also be a lot more readable, I suspect.

Do you really need to keep the collection as a collection of strings anyway? If they're *just* dates, convert it to a collection of some date type (ideally using Joda Time or Java 8's `java.time` package). If they're something like log entries which have a date but also other information, convert them into a representation of that first. Either way, you've then got a collection which more naturally represents the information it holds.

Comment: Oooh, here is the trick, months in Java are 0-based... That's really weird.
Thanks for opening that trick for me!

Comment: @DenisYakovenko: That's the immediate problem - but please don't just take that lesson away. There are other ways of improving this code very significantly...

Comment: Well, the array sorting is only a small part of the task, and I'm obliged to use Java 7, but I'll stick to your advice)
What do you mean by "very significantly"? You mean that using regex in such a way is way too expensive?

Comment: @DenisYakovenko: No, I wasn't concerned about the performance at all - I'm concerned about the readability. Using something which is designed for date/time parsing instead of regular expressions makes it much clearer what's going on, and as I say I'd try to transform the collection into a richer representation first - again, it'll improve the readability.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call `.getTime()` on the calendars and sort by the dates? or `.getTime().getTime()` and sort the longs?